# Splunk percentage value for each category

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

I have 2 columns `service` and `status`. How do I calculate percentage availability for each service.

```
total count for that service -> ts
5xx status for that service  -> er_s

availability = ((ts - er_s) / ts) * 100
```

I am able to get as a whole or separate result for each service, but I am looking for availability for each app, in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried so far?  Did it include a `stats` command to compute the totals and an `eval` to calculate the availability?

```
... | stats count as ts, sum(eval(status>=500 AND status<=599)) as er_s by service
| eval availability=((ts - er_s) * 100 / ts)
```

Comment: Ah, this is simpler. This works like charm.

My search was complicated.
`
...
| eval Count5xx=if((service="serviceA") AND (status like "5%"),1,0) 
| eval d_t = if((service="serviceA"),1,0)  
| stats sum(Count5xx) as Count5xx count(d_t) as Total 
| eval AvailablePercentage=(Total - Count5xx)*100/Total
| table service, AvailablePercentage
`